# How can I fixed the SSLException in AM?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

> I invoked the API by postman successfully but did not in HttpClient as the shown below.
>   And there are no logs in wso2carbon.log or error.log

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <14.201.60.216> != <localhost>
```

and Do I have to generate my own KeyStore if I want to use httpclient to inovke the linux's API?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Hostname verification. To do that set the following property when starting the server

```
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll
```

You can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Enabling+HostName+Verification

Comment: what is the APIM version that you use?

Comment: and how to check the carbon kernel's version

Comment: check the jar version of org.wso2.carbon.core

Comment: It is version 4.4.7. oh ,It does not support the function.

Comment: -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll will work for carbon 4.4.11 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new keystore with CN as your domain. Follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@dunithd/wso2-das-how-to-fix-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-160c13bc8fe7#.tgh16eu4s

Comment: I did the above as you say. Although,There is no sslexception,But the API was not invoked by postman or httpclient. It prompted that curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.test.foo.com port 8243: Connection timed out